# My Mac wont connect to a new wifi network

Tags: wifi

So I moved to a new place for my university and I attempted to connect to the wifi network. My HP laptop was able to connect instantly once I put in the wifi password. My Mac recognizes the network but when I put in the same password it says the password is invalid.

I have checked and double checked to make sure I have the right password a million times. Any reason why it's not connecting? My OS X version is 10.6.8.

Comment: Have you checked Console for messages from the Network subsystem? Might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: For some reason when I checked an hour later, the Wifi I was trying to connect to had two separate channels. I tried both and one of them connected with the Mac. Any reason why there was only one Wifi before but there is two now? Just curious in-case i have another issue.

Comment: Now when i checked later tonight, the wifi that I connected to no longer exists. I really need to get internet for my classes. Any way to get a quick fix? I checked the console and it says nothing.

Comment: When I check the Airport in System Profiler, it lists the two different wifi. But when I search with my Airport, it cannot find this second wifi.